# Signing and Verifying rsa signature in polarssl c

Tags: c, encryption, rsa, polarssl

I am working on using RSA encryption in an embedded system. for this i'll be using polarssl code.

I had got the encryption working on 128 bit but i am having trouble with the signature part. 
When i run the code, i get a padding error on the verify (POLARSSL_ERR_RSA_INVALID_PADDING                   -0x4100)

Below is the code. Problem code is towards the end and the top lines are about the encryption. Still helpful for background info.

```
int main()
{
    size_t len;
    rsa_context rsa;
    unsigned char rsa_plaintext[PT_LEN];
    unsigned char rsa_decrypted[PT_LEN];
    unsigned char rsa_ciphertext[KEY_LEN];
    unsigned char rsa_hash[PT_LEN];
    unsigned char rsa_sig_out[PT_LEN];
    unsigned char rsa_hash_result[PT_LEN];

rsa_init( &rsa, RSA_PKCS_V15, 0 );
rsa.len = KEY_LEN;

mpi_read_string( &rsa.N , 16, RSA_N  );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.E , 16, RSA_E  );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.D , 16, RSA_D  );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.P , 16, RSA_P  );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.Q , 16, RSA_Q  );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.DP, 16, RSA_DP );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.DQ, 16, RSA_DQ );
mpi_read_string( &rsa.QP, 16, RSA_QP );

// Checking the public and private keys
if( rsa_check_pubkey(  &rsa ) != 0 ||
    rsa_check_privkey( &rsa ) != 0 ) {
    printf( "Public/Private key error! \n" );
    exit(0);
}

memcpy( rsa_plaintext, RSA_PT, PT_LEN );

if( rsa_pkcs1_encrypt( &rsa, &myrand, NULL, RSA_PUBLIC, PT_LEN,
                       rsa_plaintext, rsa_ciphertext ) != 0 ) {
    printf( "Encryption failed! \n" );
    exit(0);
}
if( rsa_pkcs1_decrypt( &rsa, &myrand, NULL, RSA_PRIVATE, &len,
                       rsa_ciphertext, rsa_decrypted,
                       sizeof(rsa_decrypted) ) != 0 ) {
    printf( "Decryption failed! \n" );
    exit(0);
}
if( memcmp( rsa_decrypted, rsa_plaintext, len ) != 0 ) {
    printf( "Compare failed! \n" );
    exit(0);
}
printf("Oh when it all falls down!\n");

// Signing and Verifying message
sha2(rsa_plaintext, len, rsa_hash, 0); //hashing the message 
if (rsa_pkcs1_sign( &rsa, &myrand, NULL, RSA_PRIVATE, SIG_RSA_SHA256, 0, rsa_hash, rsa_sig_out ) != 0) {
    printf( "Signing failed! \n" );
    exit(0);
}
/*
if (rsa_pkcs1_verify( &rsa, NULL, NULL, RSA_PUBLIC, SIG_RSA_SHA256, 0, rsa_sig_out, rsa_hash_result ) != 0) {
    printf( "Verifying signature failed! \n" );
    exit(0);
}
*/
printf("Error Message!:%d \n", rsa_pkcs1_verify( &rsa, NULL, NULL, RSA_PUBLIC,
SIG_RSA_SHA256, 0, rsa_sig_out, rsa_hash_result ));
exit(0);

if( memcmp( rsa_hash, rsa_hash_result, len ) != 0 )
{
    printf( "Signature not verified! \n" );
    exit(0);
}
rsa_free(&rsa);

return 0;
```

}

Anybody know how i can solve this and go on ahead. Please let me know. Thanks I am running this on MinGw gcc compiler for windows. The rsa code has dependencies on bignum, md and sha2.

Comment: What version of PolarSSL do you use?

Comment: Sure would have been nice for OP to include variable and function declarations.

Comment: @Paul I am using PolarSSL version 1.2.10.

Comment: @chux The variable declarations are not relevant in this case. I did that outside the main. 
Anyways, here is RSA_N


#define RSA_N   "9292758453063D803DD603D5E777D788" \
                "8ED1D5BF35786190FA2F23EBC0848AEA" \
                "DDA92CA6C3D80B32C4D109BE0F36D6AE" \
                "7130B9CED7ACDF54CFC7555AC14EEBAB" \
                "93A89813FBF3C4F8066D2D800F7C38A8" \
                "1AE31942917403FF4946B0A83D3D3E05" \
                "EE57C6F5F5606FB5D4BC6CD34EE0801A" \
                "5E94BB77B07507233A0BC7BAC8F90F79"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the hash fails is because you didn't fill `rsa_hash` before signing or `rsa_hash_result` before verification.

`rsa_pkcs1_sign()` and `rsa_pkcs1_verify()` sign and verify the hash presented. They do not make the hash as they do not know the data. (i.e. `rsa_plaintext` and `rsa_ciphertext` never enter the sign or verify functions).

So before you call `rsa_pkcs1_sign()` you should run `sha256(rsa_plaintext, rsa_hash);` or `sha256(rsa_ciphertext, rsa_hash);` (depending on how your 'protocol' works).

Then before verify, you run `sha256(XXX, rsa_hash_result);` and provide that value to `rsa_pkcs1_verify()` so that it can actually verify your hash.

Comment: I assume that the hashing function won't pad the hash of the plaintext. Sending it to `rsa_pkcs1_verify()` after `sha256()` looks to me to be bound to fail, right? I don't know how polarssl works, but maybe the user has to take care of padding himself, i.e. explicitly pass a hash to a padding function (something like `rsa_pkcs1_pad_message()`) before encrypting it

Comment: @Pankrates It does indeed. You can pad yourself if you want, but if you indicate it is a SHA256 hash (SIG_RSA_SHA256), the `rsa_pkcs1_sign()` function will pad and sign, and `rsa_pkcs1_verify()` will check padding on the presented signature and verify it against the presented hash.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the advice. It seems i hadn't clearly understood how the signature works!

Comment: @Paul My assumption was that I would hash the plain text and then use that hash for both the signature and verification just as the encrypt/decrypt works? Why isn't this so? 

So, for the second hash, do i hash the cipher text or the output of the 1st hash?  Am a bit confused on this and now am just trying   out stuff?

Comment: @Timmay For signature and verification you use the same process to hash. So you are correct! But in your example you never made a hash in verify result, you just provided a variable called `rsa_hash_result` to the verification function but never 'filled' it with the hash to verify, so a random hash (whatever is in `rsa_hash`) is verified against at that moment. The verification function **does not** return the hash in the signature to you..

Comment: @Timmay So probably add `sha2(rsa_decrypted, len, rsa_hash_result, 0);` before the verify function and it will work.. (Not tested)

Comment: @Paul: Most definitely. Thanks a lot for the assistance. I was able to solve it using your advice. Now i understand this encryption better!